# How to use model.fit generator

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I have this variable

```
#Data Preprocessing
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=images_train,target_size=(1024,1024),class_mode='categorical',batch_size=32)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
val_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=images_valid,target_size=(1024,1024),class_mode='categorical',batch_size=32)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
test_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=images_test,target_size=(1024,1024),class_mode='categorical',batch_size=32)
```

And I want to input in model.fit but I don't know how. It's keeping error

This is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-032c8242ff66> in <module>
      2                     steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator)//32,
      3                     epochs=20,validation_data=val_generator,
----> 4                     validation_steps=len(val_generator)//32)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1418         logs = tf_utils.sync_to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
   1419         if logs is None:
-> 1420           raise ValueError('Unexpected result of `train_function` '
   1421                            '(Empty logs). Please use '
   1422                            '`Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or '

ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

How do I use the model.fit function?

Answer (score 0):

before calling `model.fit(x, y)` please compile it first by:

```
model.compile()
```

Ref:

https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/

Comment: I already compile it, but it keeps making errors. 
My training data is only 200 images, and it turns out that it was too big when I used 32 batch sizes. Then I reduced it to size 8 and the code runs, but the accuracy is at number 1, and the error is 0. What batch size do you think I should use?

Comment: The number of batch size is depends on your memory, I think 8, 16, 32, is good as it's not really an important parameter

Comment: I still can't find where my code still error with those values of batch size but thanks for your help.